# Are the components returned from higher-order components called closures?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, higher-order-components

I have a higher-order component `FormBuilder` like this:

```
const FormBuilder = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const name = 'bob';

  return class HOC extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div> 
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I am thinking that the `HOC` component that is being returned from this function can be thought of as a closure because it has access to its props(own scope), variable `name` and component `WrappedComponent`(outer function's scope) as well as anything defined in the global scope. Anyone can verify whether my thinking is right?

Comment: _A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared. This environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time the closure was created._ ([ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures))

Comment: They are closures according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures definition, but it's unlikely they are often *called* so because this doesn't explain anything; any function can be considered a closure in JS.

Comment: `HOC` is not a closure, but `HOC.prototype.render` is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes component return from higher level component
(HOC) can be treated as closure. With the help of closure we can maintain state by storing value in a variable which can be accessible by inner function. In case of higher order component as well we can maintain state by defining state at higher level component and can pass that state to low level component and by calling event function on props we can send data back to Higher Order Component.

**Difference:**
In case of closure we don't have a control on conditional rendering. If we want to render only child component we can easily do in case of higher order component by ShouldComponentUpdate() life cycle method but we can't do in closure.
In case of closure function2, function3, function4 have access to variable x

```js
function1(){
  var x = 4;
    return function2(){
      return function3(){
      return function4(){
      }
      }
      }
      }
```

In case of higher order component we have a control on what data to send to lower component. We can make x available to function1 and function2 by sending as props but we have option not to send to function3 as well as function4. In this way we can have more control in case of higher order component. All the component will have there own copy of x variable.

Comment: "*With the help of closure we can maintain state by storing value in a variable which can be accessible by inner function.*" - yes, we could do that, but this is not the distinguishing feature of closures.